# Formulating a game in an economic setting

Tags: game-theory, economics

I'm trying to teach myself Game Theory, and have come across the following question:

> Suppose that a company, $L$, produces left shoes only, and a company $R$ produces right-shoes. If $L$ charges $p_{L}$ for a left shoe, and $R$ charges $p_{R}$ for a right-shoe, then the price of a pair of shoes is $p = p_{R} + p_{L}$. The quantity of pairs of shoes purchased is given by the formula $q = 100 - p$. The cost of production is $c>0$ per shoe. Both firms choose prices simultaneously and independently of each other.
>
> Formulate this situation as a game (specify the players, strategies and payoff functions).

So clearly the two players in the game are the two firms, $L$ and $R$. However, I am unsure how to identify the strategies, there are three possible scenarios:

$$\begin{cases}p_{L} < p_{R} \\
p_{L} = p_{R} \\
p_{L} > p_{R}\end{cases}$$

Are these the correct strategies? Moreover, I am confused by how to compute the payoff for each player? I'm quite new to game theory and economics, so any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To clarify:  There are a fixed number of shoes being produced (regardless of sale price)?  From the formula for $q$ it looks like $100$ are going to be made (as it is impossible to sell more than $100$). Or can they avoid waste (producing exactly the number of shoes which the market will absorb)?

Comment: @lulu I believe that they can avoid waste, and will produce exactly the number of shoes that the market will absorb. Or at least the situation doesn't specify otherwise?

Comment: Certainly simplifies things.  Assuming that, then I'd start by looking at the "collusion" price, $p_0$...the optimal price they would settle on if they were allowed (and able) to collude on pricing.  Each player can compute that. Strategy, then, for each player is to consider the consequences of setting the price above or below $p_0$.

Comment: The payoff to the left player is $(p_L-c) \times \max(100-p_L-p_R,0)$ and to the right player is $(p_R-c)\times \max(100-p_L-p_R,0)$.  The strategies for each player are to set a price, and (as a result of dominance) they are unlikely to set a price below $c$ or above $100-c$. It is unclear whether prices need to be integers.

Comment: In most games, a mixed strategy is best.  Pick $p_L=n$ with probability $a_n$, so that $a_1+a_2+...+a_{100}=1$

Comment: @Michael: This is not most games (or most markets): for example if the cost per shoe is $c=20$ then I think the optimal collusive prices here may be $p_L=p_R=35$ and $q=30$ while the non-collusive equilibrium prices are closer to $p_L=p_R=40$ and $q=20$, a worse result for both the producers and the the customers.

Comment: @Henry, I think I understand; I formulate the problem in terms of each players payoff (their profit) and then maximize to get $p_{L}$ as a function of $p_{R}$, then using symmetry arguments, $p_{L} = p_{R} = p^{*}$, get $$p^{*} = \frac{100 + c}{3}$$. However, how would I formally write the strategy?

Comment: I do not know what "writing the strategy" actually means, but I would have thought something like $ p_L^{*} = \frac{100 + c}{3}$ and $p_R^{*} $ $= \frac{100 + c}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Players: {L,R} Strategies {$p_L$,$p_R$}, $p_i$ $\in$[0,$\infty$], payoffs are
$(p_L -c_L) (100-(p_L+p_R))$ and similar for R. Slightly more complicated if firms can used a mixed strategy, putting a probability distribution over prices, but that usually isn't done in simple oligopoly games such as this.